# How to apply a global animated background for angular components?

Tags: css, angular

I don't really understand, as whenever I try to use one (example: https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/QMwObb) whenever I try to apply it to my index.html (the global one), it goes on TOP of my content and makes everything else unclickable. Probably something simple I'm missing, right?

My main index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my global styles file I just import bootstrap and put in the css that I linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make main.component.html that manages routing and view order then you can tweak z-index on your css

```
<div class="background"></div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The z-index CSS property sets the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants or flex items. Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.

Comment: Never knew that such a property as z-index existed. Thanks!

Comment: We are here to help each other :D